# Clickable status bar in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

After click on state in statusbar I need change state, below is my example what else do I need to add?

```
state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'New'),
        ('pending', 'To Renew'),
        ('close', 'Expired'),
    ], string='Status', default='draft')


    @api.multi
    def set_as_pending(self):
        return self.write({'state': 'pending'})

    @api.multi
    def set_as_close(self):
        return self.write({'state': 'close'})
```

.xml

```
<field name="state" widget="statusbar" clickable="1" />
```

Comment: The click in the statusbar will already change the `state`, because in view it represents the field (your xml shows that).

Comment: @CZoellner Tnx for answer, in my solution after click I don't see any change. I don't know where is problem.

Answer (score 1):

The link between the clicable statusbar and the functions must be an onchange method. I think you could add something like this:

```
@api.onchange('state')
def onchange_state(self):
    if self.state == 'pending':     
        self.write({'state': 'pending'})
    #... your other states
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: at least it reaches the onchange?

Answer (score 1):

Clickable Should be Equal to `Boolean` Not `Integer`

`clickable = "True"` instead of `clickable="1"`

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<field name="status" options="{'clickable': '1'}" widget="statusbar"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

To have a working clickable status, the field should be of type **Many2one**. Clickable does not work with "Selection".